# Images from website aren't loading on Apple Devices

Tags: html, css, ios, image, web

I created a website using HTML and CSS and there are a lot of images on the website. However, for some reason about 20 of the images don't load in on Apple devices. On desktop and my android phone all images load fine but on my iPad and an iPhone I tested it out on they don't load, only an alt tag is displayed. Can anyone help me fix this? I have had a look to see what is common about all of the pictures that load and I can't seem to find any similarities. They are all around the same file size, even the ones that load being bigger on some a lot of occasions. The URL is https://www.fredsfashionboutique.com/ if you would like to have a look for yourself. On the home page they all seem to load fine but in the clothing section they don't.

TIA, 
Freddie

Comment: The images are showing on my iPad (iPadOS 13.4.1) (Safari) normally. You might want to check that the browser you're using allows images.

Comment: Ohh that's odd - did you check on the clothing section? Because normally the only image that is displayed on that one is the jumpers and the others just display the alt tag. And I tried on my older iPad and my brothers iPhone X and they only displayed some of the images. I would have thought if some images were loading then the browser would allow it... But I'm not sure

Comment: I'm trying to add a picture but for some reason its not letting me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its to do with the image itself, not sure what though.

**The fix:**
Go to image link > Copy Image > Open photo editing program > Paste image (*don't open the image, make sure to paste it, its something to do with the metadata*) > Export as **.png** > reupload to site.

Testing image: https://www.titusstudios.net/data/static/images/miscellaneous/04052020/neilbarret.png